# Espocrm pdf printing

Tags: pdf, espocrm

Eu tenho cinco registros com informações iguais e diferentes em uma página de informações do espocrm, eu preciso criar um modelo em pdf, que me traga as informações de todos os registros selecionados em uma única folha

---

I have five records with the same and different information on an espocrm information page, I need to create a pdf model that brings me the information of all selected records in a single sheet

Eu tentei usar o {{#each}} em varias formas, e não consigo resolver.

Answer (score 0):

If your target entity is linked to parent entity then you need to define the pdf template for the parent entity and use the {{#each}} helper.

ex: you need to print contacts on an account, then you need to define the pdf template to the account instead of contacts, same is for invoice and items.

In case there is no parent link between the records and want to print directly from the list page you have the mass action print to PDF, but this will lead to have every ebtity printed into separated pdf page, note that this time the pdf template must be in the target entity like Contact or Invoice Item for example.

You also can export them from the list page into excel or csv and then convert to pdf outside espocrm.